# getting error "Can't read row# 0, col# 2 from CursorWindow. Make sure your Cursor is initialized correctly."

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing Android app. I'm trying to display a user input, however when I try to do that I get the above error message. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Here is a code I use. Thank You.

```
try {

        Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT catgram FROM adresse_definition WHERE definition='"+word[0].toLowerCase().trim()+"'", null);

        //Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT index_nom_adresse" + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() + " FROM adresse_definition JOIN   definition ON adresse_definition.definition = definition.data_id ", null);
        //Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().query("adresse_definition", null, "index_nom_adresse= '" + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() + "' or definition= '" + word[0].toUpperCase().trim() + "' ", null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

            if (word[1] == null || word[1].equals("English")) {
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(2);
            } else {
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(1);
            }
        } else {
            translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
        translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
    }

    dictionary.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are selecting all the columns in your rawquery that you're going to get from cursor. Right now you are selecting only one column in you query and getting two columns in cursor.getString. Simply change the query to:

```
Select * from table_name Where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is reading only one column in the Cursor and column indexes are zero based.

```
"SELECT catgram FROM adresse_definition WHERE definition=word[0].toLowerCase().trim()";
```

Comment: getting a new error message now:  SqliteDatabaseCpp(622): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "[0]": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.example.application/databases/dict.db